# Why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion

I want to know why the following question was closed. [closed question on dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/334/tricky-question-on-so-can-you-identify-this/339)

That question is nothing, but a link to a valid question on SO ( with an excepted wrong answer there).

I agree that a valid question has to be more than a link, but I think that some comments why the question is closed would help to make it more transparent and give the questioner a chance to rewrite it as valid question.

I state, that the original question from SO What programming language is this? would be a perfectly valid question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisely because — as you said — "that question is nothing but a link."

The text of the question (the information contained on *this* site) should be as complete as possible. A large percentage of your traffic will come from search engines and simply placing a link in a question does *nothing* for this site. If the user couldn't be bothered to actually *ask* a question, it should be closed.

Comment: I wanted that question to be migrated. I figured mine should be closed, but while people were fleshing out the site I wanted to see if anyone recognized it.

Comment: @drachenstern: No problem. If you would like to see the question asked on this site, go ahead and ask it.